Is there a gaseous or liquid precursor to metallic lanthanum?
How to deposit a thin layer of lanthanum metal inside the porous structure of a gel? The gel itself is not going to react with $\ce{La}$ but how to make sure that the byproducts  are removable by solvent exchange after the deposition process? Alternatively, if the precursors are necessarily vapors, aerogel must be used as a template.
Which approach to try:

Make the gel electrically conductive (by adding carbon to it), use a nonmetallic solvent, and deposit $\ce{La}$ electrolytically from a solution.
Find a thermally activated set of precursors (I don't know any), heat until decomposition yields $\ce{La}$ without any unwanted solid products.

Without other reactants, some of the most volatile $\ce{La}$ compounds apparently always yield solid compounds on pyrolysis, along with hydrogen-rich gas. For example:

pyrolysis of rare earth Cp compounds at temperatures > 500 °C is known
to yield primarily H2 as the gas-phase product.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7079703/

Lanthanum chloride melts at 858C, and the vapor has been used in CVD deposition of, e.g., borides. See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022369797002308 for example.

Boranes may react at way lower temperature than hydrogen gas (if the latter reacts at all).  Too high temperature destroys the aerogel, I think. Only metallic lanthanum is needed, not $\ce{LaB6}$ .

Is the gel an aerogel or a hydrogel ?

The point is that the chloride vapor has been used in a CVD process. Yes, you will need to figure out the rest…

@Maurice Definitely not hydrogel, since lanthanum reacts with water. Aerogel could be an option, if no liquid solvent was suitable.

It also appears that people have made La(hfac)3 (Condorelli et al., Chem. Vap. Deposition 2001, 7, No. 4, 151). While they targeted it at growing LaF3, it might be conceivable to grow straight La films with it based on the ability to grow pure Cu films from Cu(hfac)2 and related precursors.

@JonCuster It's not that easy. While copper is deposited from many different precursors,  lanthanum forms compounds. Here is a long list for all the elements: https://atomiclimits.com/alddatabase/?fbclid=IwY2xjawFMKMBleHRuA2FlbQIxMAABHZrbycfBpTPTrKBRDWtyOU0jUKoTHEBEymeUsWuMpHEZXmE3dN81Eak6Tg_aem_Lw2kaHba0EI6eiCchhvJKQ

@PaulKolk - all that list shows is that people have CVD precursors for La. It does not show successful growth of metallic La, but does not say if anyone has ever tried it. There are many technology reasons to grow the oxides, but I don't see a push for metallic La thin films. If it were me, I would try La(hfac) plus a hydrogen plasma for starters  (or a number of the other precursors that might well have ligands that come off nicely in a reducing H environment). Getting Cu was not easy either, particularly working out a process for low resistivity Cu. Ask me how I know...

@JonCuster Note that H is actually oxidizing to La. Even at temperatures as high as 1200K, the stoichiometry is about $\ce{La10H15}$ (at 300K, $\ce{La10H28}$, for comparison) (I haven't found data for higher temperatures than 1200K, but I suspect the decomposition to La happens above my planned experiment's upper limit of 1380K).
