Is electroplating possible in a solvent that doesn't dissociate precursor molecules?
There are metalorganic compounds, soluble in nonpolar solvents without dissociation into ions. Is it possible, in some rare cases, to apply voltage to submerged electrodes so that it causes the metalorganic solute to dissociate and electroplate the metal?
If so, what forms at the other electrode?

Most of the voltage would be spent on the Ohmic gradient in the isolant solvent.

@Poutnik I'm not trying to make a fast or energy-efficient process. It's only an experiment. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/184743/is-there-a-gaseous-or-liquid-precursor-to-metallic-lanthanum

It would be probably dangerous combination of flammable solvent, highly flammable metallic compound and sparks.

@Poutnik Given the sensitivity of these materials to air and water, there is no hope to perform the electrolysis outside of argon filled box. Anyway, I'm still purely theorizing right now, I don't have access to any lab. Maybe in the future I will do it, maybe not-- depends on whether it looks doable.

Sure, I am theorizing as well.

If nonionic organometallic compounds dissociate to ions at all in organic solvents, they do so without application of an external electric field. At the level of fundamental forces, wherever the electronic structure is suitable the  molecular-level electric fields that drive the dissociation are far more intense than what we can produce macroscopically in our electrolytic cells.
Ionically dissociable organometallic compounds require a strongly electropositive metal or metal complex combined with a moiety that can form a relatively stable carbanion. Two closely related candidates meeting these requirements are lithium cyclopentadienide, $\ce{C5H5Li}$[1] and magnesocene, $\ce{(C5H5)2Mg}$[2].
For the lithium compound[1]:

The donor base DIGLYME gives the solvent-separated ion pair (SSIP) $\ce{[(DIGLYME)2Li][(η^5 - Cp)2Li]}$.

And for its magnesium counterpart [2]:

Unlike ferrocene, bis($\eta^5$-cyclopentadienyl)magnesium (magnesocene, $\ce{MgCp2}$) is slightly dissociated in solvents, such as ethers, resulting in electrolyte solutions with low conductivity. $\ce{MgCp2}$/tetrahydrofuran solutions make possible reversible magnesium plating and stripping with low over-potentials for many cycles.

References

Reent Michel, Regine Herbst-Irmer, Dietmar Stalke."Revealing Coordination Patterns in $\ce{C5}$-Cyclic Lithium Organics". Organometallics 2011, 30, 16, 4379–4386. https://doi.org/10.1021/om200471e.

Rainer Schwarz, Dr. Marijana Pejic, Philipp Fischer, Dr. Mario Marinaro, Dr. Ludwig Jörissen, Dr. Mario Wachtler. "Magnesocene-Based Electrolytes: A New Class of Electrolytes for Magnesium Batteries". _Angewandte Chemie International Edition 2016, 55, 48, 14958-14962. https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201606448.


